# Connection refused to aws instance

Tags: networking, connection, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect my AWS instance from my Linux box but getting "ssh: connect to host ec2-18-112-897-24.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused" this error all the times.
Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Your host cannot be found on the public internet. Make sure you are able to connect first. You can also try with `nc ec2-18-112-897-24.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com 22`. Check your security group settings.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some common solutions:

- Make sure your VPC has an internet gateway
- Make sure you update your route table so that 0.0.0.0/0 is routed to the internet gateway
- Make sure your instance has a public or elastic IP address
- Make sure your security group has allowed port 22 from the IP address you want to access the instance from
- Make sure your network access control lists allow appropriate ingress and egress, which is port 22 inbound and ephemeral ports outbound